# Pagination: Previous/Next link alignment

Tags: css, web, pagination, blogs

I'm creating a new blog design right now that features a sort of pagination where there is a list of posts, followed by a link to the next (older posts) and the previous page (newer posts).

I was wondering if there is any good advice on how to align these buttons, i.e. which one goes left, which one goes right?

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="left">
        <a href="#">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="#">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pagination .left {
    float: left;
}

.pagination .right {
    float: right;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKVp3/

Is this the way you want it? "Previous" on the left side, "next" on the right side?

Comment: The question wasn't how to implement it. It's more about which label to align left and which one to align right.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd have older posts on the left and newer posts on the right. It's a bit like turning a page on a book. Left to ->  right